# React-Redux / useSelector hook and Provider give me some Problems

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Ok here I'm again. I begin to implement a Redux store in my React App written in TypeScript and try to learn how react works with redux.

So maybe its easy maybe not. I have a store ok thats a global single object (singleton i guess). So and this object can have all my states in it. This states could be objects with a single value or objects with a array in it.

What i dont understand is the useSelector Hook.

I have this component:

```
export const ShoppingCartComponent = () => {
    const totalPrice = useSelector(state => state.totalPriceOfAllProducts)

    return <>(
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0" className={"shoppingCart"}>
            <Card>
                <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
                    Click me!
                </Accordion.Toggle>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                        <Card.Body>
                            {totalPrice}
                        </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
        </Accordion>
    )</>
}
```

So the useSelector hook accept a selectorFunction and is called with the entire redux store. Is that correct?

Maybe i dont understand it right. Do i need to implement a custom selectorFunction and then pass it as an argument?

Because in materials that i found, it looks easy like that:

const someValue = useSelector(state => state.theValueWhatIWant)

I use ReduxToolkit because it is recommend from the redux team itself to use.

React give me this error that i dont understand:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
./src/index.tsx/<
F:/Workspaces/Frontend/testreact_ts/src/index.tsx:10

   7 | import store from "./store/store";
   8 | import {Provider} from "react-redux";
   9 | 
> 10 | ReactDOM.render(
  11 |     <Provider store={store}>
  12 |         <BrowserRouter>
  13 |           <React.StrictMode>
```

But i need the Provider right? It even says me, that is the entire store and thats ok but of course the store is a object. And now I'm not allowed to pass that object as a Provider?

Store looks like that:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {totalPriceOfAllProductsReducer} from "./features/totalPriceOfAllProductsSlice";
import {productsInShoppingCartReducer} from "./features/productsInShoppingCart";

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        totalPriceOfAllProductsReducer,
        productsInShoppingCartReducer,
    }
})
```

Thanks again for any help :-)

Have a nice day

EDIT:
I created a sandbox again: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-store-question-ghmm3

Comment: It looks like `totalPrice` in this instance is an object. Can you `console.log` it and see what's being set? I assume it should just be a number?

Comment: If it's an object, you need to change `{totalPrice}` to something like `{totalPrice.value}` or whichever keys you have in that object you want to display.